# Reset listpreference radio button chiose after every selection

Tags: java, android, radiobuttonlist, listpreference, preferencefragment

I need to reset the choice of radio button in list preference after every selection.

I need that because every time the user selects a choice I open a new activity with some data to show but if I have a default choice and the user selects the same the app doesn't open any activity because the events are onSharedPreferenceChanged and the event doesn't run.

This is my code:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
{
    if(key.equals("getReport_radioPreference")){

        Preference pref = findPreference(key);
        ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) pref;
        String i = ((ListPreference) pref).getValue();



    }
}
```

And this is my list preference:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="listArray">
    <item>Last week</item>
    <item>Last month</item>
    <item>last year</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="listValues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

And my preferences:

```
<ListPreference
    android:title="Clicca qui"
    android:summary="Clicca qui"
    android:key="getReport_radioPreference"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:entries="@array/listArray"
    android:entryValues="@array/listValues" />
```

pic: